# call a Async Method multiple times problem in silverlight

Tags: silverlight

Hi i am calling a Async method with different parameter value multiple times giving same result in completed event.

```
client.ListAllLookupValuesByTypeCompleted += client_ListAllAddressFormatCompleted;
client.ListAllLookupValuesByTypeAsync("AddressFormat");

client.ListAllLookupValuesByTypeCompleted += client_ListAllPhoneFormatCompleted;
client.ListAllLookupValuesByTypeAsync("PhoneFormat");



void client_ListAllAddressFormatCompleted(object sender, ListAllLookupValuesByTypeCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            cmbAddressFormat.ItemsSource = e.Result;
        }


void client_ListAllPhoneFormatCompleted(object sender, ListAllLookupValuesByTypeCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            cmbPhonePrintFormat.ItemsSource = e.Result;
        }
```

please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: When I had the same problem, I extended the service client class (it is a partial class) and added my own methods which use internal BeginSomeOperation and EndSomeOperation methods. It was impossible to create new instance of the service each time because I needed to use sessions.

Comment: when someone answers your question, click on green tick next to that answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create new instance of `client`.

```
...
var client = new XyzClient();
client.ListAllLookupValuesByTypeCompleted += client_ListAllAddressFormatCompleted;
client.ListAllLookupValuesByTypeAsync("AddressFormat");

client = new XyzClient();
client.ListAllLookupValuesByTypeCompleted += client_ListAllPhoneFormatCompleted;
client.ListAllLookupValuesByTypeAsync("PhoneFormat");
...


void client_ListAllAddressFormatCompleted(object sender, ListAllLookupValuesByTypeCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    cmbAddressFormat.ItemsSource = e.Result;
}


void client_ListAllPhoneFormatCompleted(object sender, ListAllLookupValuesByTypeCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   cmbPhonePrintFormat.ItemsSource = e.Result;
}
```

Another solution would be to make the second call in the handler of the first one (probably creating new client instance anyway).